# Width of the Dropdown on ASP.NET MVC View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how we can set the width of the Dropdown.
When i write the below line of code, I am getting compilation error.

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("product", (SelectList) ViewData["product"], new { style = "width: 300px;"})%>
```

because I think ViewData["product"] is considered as object so its thinks it is the overload html attributes

Comment: This problem goes away altogether if you use the best practice of using a strongly typed ViewModel instead of ViewData.